# How to stop water running down shower tube and under the bath

Tags: water, shower, bathtub

We've got a corner jacuzzi bath tub with a shower attachment. The shower tube goes through a hole and via a spring so that the tube retracts automatically. The problem is that water collects on the floor under the bath tub when it runs down the shower hose, through the hole where the shower tube retracts and onto the floor below. Does anyone know of any solution for this problem? Is there some sort of circular rubber flange that you can put the shower tube through to stop this happening. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the pictures, that was very helpful. While I wouldn't want to restrict the hose retraction, I don't think there's any other option than to do so. Your situation is worse than I expected & you are stuck with a very poorly planned installation.

But, I think you could go any of 3-ways as still keep your tub wash-down capabilities, as pictured below:

1 - Is to minimally re-plumb with a new hose to a proper tub mount, a short connecting hose below the tub & a longer hose above. ([**below are the best match I found**](http://www.homedepot.com/s/chrome%2520elbow?NCNI-5).) Presuming you have access from the other side of the wall or could install an access panel there for future servicing of the tub.

2 - Is to cover & seal the existing tub mount with an escutcheon & grommet, the grommet's slit would seat inside the escutcheon's hole shoulder. The hose could pull out further, but not retract down to the tub. You'll want an escutcheon that's only slightly larger than the tub mount's diameter.

3 - Is to cover & seal the tub mount a little sloppily with a Hinged Flange & O-ring on top. This is the most flexible as you could easily remove the Hinged Flange & the O-ring would slip through the tub mount's port.

[image: Shower Hosed]

Comment: No, I have replaced the shower tube and checked that it is tight and secure and it still happens. It just seems to be in the normal course of the shower.

Comment: Could you post a picture? If there's a wall a chase could be made or the hose port could be moved there. Or, an elbow port may be able to replace the drop-in port. Ultimately, the only solution might be to put a dog collar on the hose.

Comment: Not sure how to upload the photos. It's next to a wall but don't think that will help. The drop-in port is part of the bath. Where would I get a dog collar from? Have you got a picture of one?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/4cdplqb3rxsdhsa/AAArYJx_XP_wObz_67B6jkcWa)

Comment: Thanks so much for that and all your advice. It's been really helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the question. I hope one of the options results in a permanent & satisfactory resolution.